# Extracting files from a zip which is already read as a string in lua

Tags: lua, zip

I have a zip file read into a string. I want to reach to its contents using [luazip](http://www.keplerproject.org/luazip/).
According to the manual, filename is given to function `zip.open(filename)`. But I need to use a string of file's content. One way is to write the string to a new zip file and pass its name to the function. But I do not want to create a new file. What is an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: There's no way to use luazip for what you want under the given restrictions, unless you would like to contribute a patch for reading from a string.

Comment: @Deduplicator thank you for your answer, so I have to create a new temporary file first :/ Just for curiosity, what is the procedure of contributing such a patch?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think the best bet is doing the work, read some on their mailing list and ask how after testing the water and showing a working patch. It was made by the kepler project, and lua-rocks is one of their projects.

Comment: the project is now hosted here: https://github.com/luaforge/luazip. fork at github and make a pull request.

Comment: if you don't want to create a physical file you could write/read to/from a named pipe or a ram filesystem.

Comment: @lipp I don't know how to do that. Can you point me in the right direction?